# Unable to display IP address after using ifconfig on ubuntu18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ip, ifconfig

all,
After using ifconfig on ubuntu18.04, can get "eno1, eno2" related information, but the IP and netmask are not displayed, but now I need this IP for remote connection operations. The following solutions are given online:

1. First use`sudo dhclient eno1` to update the IP address
2. Then run `sudo ifconfig eno1`
3. `reboot`
   When I execute `sudo dhclient eno1`, the terminal is stuck for a long time without responding.
   I would like to ask how can I get my ubuntu IP.
   Looking forward to your answer~
   [return when run "ifconfig"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmoq4.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure that the network interface is not up. Try `ifup eno1`. Also look into `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` if you want the interface to start on boot. If the corresponding file is not there you may have to generate it.